# Is the term scalars a synonym for the elements of $\mathbb R^1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Are scalars a synonym for the elements of $\mathbb R^1$ or is there a subtle difference between them?

Comment: Since this question is tagged linear algebra I suppose you're talking about vector spaces, in this case a scalar is an element of the field over which your vector space is defined

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R$, the real numbers? Use `\mathbb R`. And no, they are not synonymous unless it was explicitly stated that all scalars in the text/course/chapter refer to the real numbers. Otherwise, it could easily be any field, like the complex numbers $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term ''scalar'' is normally used in the context of vector spaces. A vector space is defined as a quadruple $(\mathbb{K},V,+,\cdot)$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field, $V$ is a set, $+$ is a binary operation in $V$ with the ususal properties of an ''addition'' and $\cdot$ is the scalar product, i.e. a product of an element of $\mathbb{K}$ with an element of $V$  with some special properties ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)).

A ''scalar'' is an element of $\mathbb{K}$.

Answer (score 2):

Scalars are usually those entities with which you can multiply a vector, i.e. elements of a field, but normally the term is used when you are talking about a vector space over said field.

Answer (score 2):

Scalars are members of whichever field is used to define your vector space.  These could be real numbers, but there are lots of other possibilities.  Complex numbers, for example.